# Different frameworks, different costs

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, monodevelop, monocross

I am looking into developing some hybrid apps for a friend who wants to get into the market.  I am confused about what the difference is between monotouch, monodroid, and monocross is though.  Monocross appears to be an open source version of monotouch/monodroid?  What's the main difference between these different frameworks?

Also is the cost of monodroid/monotouch the same $999 a year?  Or is that $999 for each platform?  I am looking to build my applications using Microsoft Visual Studios or XCode if possible, along with HTML/CSS for the placements of things and such.  This way the application can work on a website in addition to on the different platforms in their respective markets.

Can someone point me in the right direction on what a novice with no experience in this field should be looking at?  Also is there an IRC for these products?

Thanks

Comment: Forums.xamarin.com would be a better place to ask questions about licensing and features

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829532/difference-between-monocross-monotouch-xamarin is the post you're looking for