# What does MvvmCross do that Xamarin doesn't already?

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, mvvmcross

Hi so I'm a newb at cross platform stuff and I'm trying to figure out what MvvmCross brings to the table.

From my poor understanding, Xamarin already allows for everything except UI stuff to be written in csharp. Where does MvvmCross come in?

Comment: An old answer to a similar question is http://stackoverflow.com/a/14871005/373321

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MvvmCross brings the MVVM pattern to platforms where it was previously unavailable, like iOS and Android.

It also supports data binding in Views. This is a powerful feature that provides great separation of concerns. The View will use the ViewModels to offer proper behaviors in the application. MvvmCross even locates the ViewModels in a dedicated project so you can easily reference and reuse them in others.

This is the most important point when talking about MvvmCross. By locating the ViewModels in a Portable Class Library (PCL), you can add them as a reference to any other projects. Of course, that’s not the only interesting point of MvvmCross. There’s also a plug-in architecture, dependency injection (DI) and more.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn759442.aspx

Answer (score 3):

> Xamarin already allows for everything except UI stuff to be written in
>   csharp.

Xamarin allows you to write UI stuff in C#.

MVVMCross (Mvx) allows you to use the MVVM pattern in cross platform development, so that you can have a shared business logic layer, **ViewModel**. So you are creating different **Views** based on the platform but binding to the same **ViewModel**.